# MVC 6 Standard Logging Messages

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am implementing logging in my MVC application.

I noticed that the following two messages are being logged automatically:

> "Information : Request successfully matched the route with name 'XXX'
>   and template 'XXX'." "Verbose : Executing action"

My question is whether or not it is possible to turn these messages off and how it is accomplished.  I am sure it is in the configuration somewhere but I have yet to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a filter that will ignore the logs you don't care about, while continuing to allow the ones you do care about (like the ones your code makes) to continue to be logged - regardless of level.

This will depend on which `LoggerProvider` you are using, or whether you are rolling your own.  As you haven't supplied any code registering your `LoggerProvider`, I'll use the [sample app from Logging/AspNet](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Program.cs#L25) as an example.  Note line #25:

```cs
factory.AddConsole((category, logLevel) => logLevel >= LogLevel.Critical &&
    category.Equals(typeof(Program).FullName)); // restricts to Program
```

The category filter above is restricting the logger to log only items that are produced by the `SampleApp.Program` object (while additionally only allowing `Critical` or higher logs, but we don't care about that bit)

Now you could go ahead and whitelist every namespace you want to log, but it's easier to blacklist the ones you don't want.  The `Microsoft.AspNet.*` libraries are pretty noisy, so you could add the following filter to stop them from logging:

```cs
factory.AddConsole((category, logLevel) => !category.StartsWith("Microsoft.AspNet"));
```

If you've rolled your own `ILogger`, then you'll just need to ensure you've included the filter as a constructor parameter and that you reference it in your implementation of `ILogger.IsEnabled`.

Comment: I had noticed the *category* parameter of the filter function.  Having used the logging framework provided by Enterprise Library in the past, I figured that the *category* parameter represented things such as "General", "Exceptions", or whatever categories the developer assigned.  I did not realize that the *category* parameter represented the type name of the source of the log entry.  Perhaps this parameter should have been named something like *source*.  At any rate, the information you provided is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JasonRichmeier well, you set the category when you create the logger, so you if you chose to you could set it to things like "General" and "Exceptions", you don't have to set it to the type name, although it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Logging has different levels, you can set it to a higher level and it will eliminate information level logging.

```
// LogLevels
//Debug = 1,
//Verbose = 2,
//Information = 3,
//Warning = 4,
//Error = 5,
//Critical = 6,
loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Warning;
```

you would set this in Startup.cs in the Configure method

Comment: I was aware of this.  This would work if I were logging things at the warning level and above but I will want to log informational messages as well.  I just don't want the other *noise* logged.  I don't need to know that a route was matched or that an action is executing.

Comment: If you knew this you did not make it clear in your question. I'm not aware of a way to disable information level logging from other code while enabling it in your own, that seems like a different question to me.

Comment: found this issues on github, looks like at least consolelogger lets you pass in a filter function so there may be ways to do this with specific loggers but not sure of a general way https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/170